# Find the first match from a list of words in a string

Tags: python

I am writing a function that finds a keyword in a string and returns the first match, if any.

The keywords are "what", "when", "who"

**Example:**

- The user inputs a string in the form of a question:
  "Who is John Connor"
- The function returns "who"

Is there a way to compare a list of keywords against a string input and return the first match?

I thought about using **re.search** but it takes single string at a time. 
This is what I have so far:

```
question = input("Ask me a question: ")
 keywords = ("what", "when", "who")
 question = question.lower()
 match = re.search(r'word:', question) #  re.search seems to take only one string at a time
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert your list to a regular expression of the form `\b(?:what|when|who)\b`, then use `re.search()`.

```
question = input("Ask me a question: ").lower()
keywords = ("what", "when", "who")
kw_re = r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(map(re.escape, keywords)) + r')\b'
match = re.search(kw_re, question)
```

`\b` matches word boundaries, so this will only match whole words.

Answer (score 1):

Testing a word for inclusion in a set of keywords is `O(1)` vs. `O(n)` for a list of `n` keywords.

```
def find_match(sentence, keyword_set):
    for word in sentence.split():
        if word in keyword_set:
            return word

keywords = {"what", "when", "who"}
question = "Who is John Connor".lower()
>>> find_match(question, keywords)
'who'
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the input into words and compare each against your set of keywords; break from the loop if a match is found, or return if you want to wrap it into a function.

```
for word in question.split():
    if word in keywords:
        match = word
        break
```

Also, take care to handle cases when no match is found.

Answer (score 0):

This will find the fist word in the list and give you the location of it:

```
question = input("Ask me a question: ")
keywords = ("what", "when", "who")
question = question.lower()

for keyword in keywords:
   loc = question.find(keyword)
   if loc == -1:
      loc = "Not Found"
   else:
       print('{} was found at location: {} and is the first match found in the list of keywords'.format(keyword, loc))
       break
```